# Determine if my custom app is installed on device by mobile browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ios

I have a question:
I have an Android app and an iOS app.
Is it possible, from a web page of my website (like the homepage) check if my app is installed and say "OPEN IN-APP", or say "DOWNLOAD APP FROM PLAYSTORE" or "DOWNLOAD APP FROM APP STORE"?
Thank you.

Comment: just give the googleplay or playstore link to your app from your website , if app is installed then it will be shown there , like open , otherwise user can download from there.